# как сделать правильный поиск в строке

Tags: javascript, поиск

есть массив

```
var arr = [
  "/",
  "/some/[foo]"
]
```

Нужно сделать поиск но вместо *foo* может быть все что угодно например:

```
var index = "/some/32"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, требуется выяснить есть ли в массиве строк некая последовательность символов.
Тогда подойдет следующее:

```js
var arr = ['text', 'text123'];

findSome('123', arr);
findSome('34', arr);

function findSome(text, array) {
  return array.some(function (str) {
    return str.indexOf(text) !== -1;
  });
}
```

Если речь просто о поиске строки в массиве, то достаточно `includes()`, можно и `indexOf()`, без `some()`.

```js
var arr = ['text1', 'text2'];
var text = 'text2';

arr.includes(text); // arr.indexOf(text) !== -1
```